# How can I import a React component in my HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm making a site with HTML, CSS & Js; and I need to import this react component.
I already followed the tutorial in https://es.reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html, but it doesn't work. I don't know how to do it.
This is the component:

```
class Card extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
        <div className="card">
          <img src={this.props.img} />
          <div className="card-body">
            <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
            <h5>{this.props.author}</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I want to write several divs in the HTML DOM with the properties for rendering a lot of cards into the page. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you mean with "it doesn't work", please? Do you see any specific error in the console? Furthermore, can you share the relevant code? Anyway, you can refer to a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/7uy8vobz/

Answer (score 0):

**in card.js**

```
   class Card extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
        <div className="card">
          <img src={this.props.img} />
          <div className="card-body">
            <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
            <h5>{this.props.author}</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Card;
```

**when you import it in the file , then use it as required like this**

```
import Card from './Card';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can render React components to an HTML page using `ReactDOM.render`.

```js
const { useEffect, useMemo, useState } = React;

const applyImg = ({ title, ...book }) =>
  ({
    title, ...book,
    img: `https://via.placeholder.com/100x180?text=${title.replace(/\s+/g, '+')}`
  });

const fetchCards = () => Promise.resolve([
  { title: 'In Search of Lost Time', author: 'Marcel Proust' },
  { title: 'Ulysses', author: 'James Joyce' },
  { title: 'Don Quixote', author: 'Miguel de Cervantes' }
].map(applyImg));

const Card = (props) => {
  const { author, img, title } = props;
  
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <img src={img} />
      <div className="card-body">
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
        <h5>{author}</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = ({ title }) => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCards().then(result => {
      setBooks(result);
    });
  }, [])

  return useMemo(() => (
    <div className="app">
      { books.map(book => <Card {...book} />) }
    </div>
  ), [books]);
};

/* Import your App as a module, into your HTML file. */
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: thin solid grey;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0.667em;
  padding: 0.33em;
}

.card-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<h1>Book List</h1>
<div id="react"></div>
```